# My script works in jsfiddle but not site. Cannot call method hover of null?

Tags: javascript, jquery, null

I'm getting an error that says "Uncaught typeError: cannot call method 'hover' of null" after
`$('#nav li a').hover(function(){` in my javascript.

site code: http://pastebin.com/GjZBEu3s
jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jenga/5rfCC/2/

Comment: This means that jQuery is not loaded.

Comment: You are using prototype.js also, it conflicts with jquery. To avoid this conflict use `jQuery` instead of `$` or use `jQuery.noConflict()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You scripting should be in the body of the document, right before the closing `</body>` tag. If it's loaded in the `<head>`, the elements it addresses in the document may not be loaded yet. See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5rfCC/3/) (notice 'no wrap (body)' in the 'Choose framework' dialog).

By the way, a similar effect could be achieved using css only. Use this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/vtkyt/) in a Chrome/webkit browser.