# jQuery slideToggle doesn't work on joomla, but works on jsbin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, joomla

So I have a website and I want to use the jQuery `slideToggle` to move the blocks. The problem is that it doesn't work on my Joomla website. However, when I copy the code to jsbin.com, it works. Here's the link http://jsbin.com/EcObOwex/1/edit
Here's the actual JS I'm using:

```
$('.sTurinys').hover(function(){
$('.ssTurinys',(this)).stop().slideToggle(600);
});
```

I don't know what additional information I can provide.
The JS code is in splash.js, link to it works properly (checked it, there's some other script that works from the file)

Edit: I was informed that it was an JS error that I was getting.
Here's the error
`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tooltip'`
And here's the code. Could anyone help me determine what is it?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEvent('load', function() {
            new JCaption('img.caption');
        });
jQuery(document).ready(function()
            {
                jQuery('.hasTooltip').tooltip({"container": false});
            });
```

I didn't add it manually, it's part of the `<jdoc:include type="head" />`. Could anyone help me determine how to shake this code off?

EDIT 2:
Some more information:
Here's my full `<head>` code. http://jsbin.com/aFOZEWI/2/edit
**AND YOU CAN ALSO FIND THE FULL SPLASH.JS in the JavaScript part of the Bin.**
P.S. The other part of the splash.js works, my overflow element changes just as it's intended.

Comment: Any console errors on your Joomla site?

Comment: Where are you adding the code to import jQuery.js and splash.js? Also, what version of Joomla are you using?

Comment: @ToddMotto not particularly, but when I inspect element with Opera, I get 1 error and 1 warning: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tooltip' apieemus:28
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.`

Comment: That'll be your problem. The uncaught TypeError will throw the exception, meaning no further JS should run - and it doesn't reach your script above. Find out why tooltip isn't defined (usually you're missing a library/plugin that contains a tooltip and you're calling it).

Comment: @Lodder They are both in the `<head>` section. The Joomla version is Joomla 3.2

Answer (score 2):

It might be possible that you have multiple jQuery libraries being imported which may cause conflicts. In addition to that, let's import the scripts and add you code using Joomla coding standards.

```
<?php      
   JHtml::_('jquery.framework'); //This calls jQuery in noConflict mode
   $doc = JFactory::getDocument();
   $doc->addScript(JUri::root() . 'templates/vabankbroker/src/splash.js');
   $doc->addScriptDeclaration("
      $('.sTurinys').hover(function(){
          $('.ssTurinys',(this)).stop().slideToggle(600);
      });
  ");
?>
```

As for the Tooltip error, open the index.php of your template and if the following doesn't exist, I would recommend you add it:

```
JHtml::_('bootstrap.framework');
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry, but neither adding the code got it working, neither did the other code remove the tooltip error.

Comment: Where are you adding this code? Can you please provide a link to your site so it can be inspected?

Comment: I added the code to the theme's index.php, at the very top of the page.

Comment: The address is http://vabankbroker.com, please select the LT language at top right to see the thing I'm trying to create.

Comment: In the splash.js, you already have `$('.sTurinys').hover(........` so either remove it from there, or remove the `$doc->addScriptDeclaration` bit of code I provided in my answer. If the Joomla version if 3.2, then why is it loading jQuery 1.8.3? It should be loading 1.10.2 as this is the version that comes with Joomla 3.2

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer through this post:

[My script works in jsfiddle but not site. Cannot call method hover of null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12293505/my-script-works-in-jsfiddle-but-not-site-cannot-call-method-hover-of-null)
Thank you for all kinds of notices, I'll make all those fixes, but for this exact problem, I had to include the script in the end of the `<body>` tag, and it started working.

Cheers :)