# jquery slidetoggle() not working in Joomla but works when not using Joomla

Tags: jquery, joomla, slidetoggle

I am using the `slidetoggle` function to show/hide a div on a Joomla 3 template.  It is not working in joomla but it is working when I use it outside of Joomla.

I read [jQuery slideToggle doesn't work on joomla, but works on jsbin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21238279/jquery-slidetoggle-doesnt-work-on-joomla-but-works-on-jsbin)

and put my script at the bottom of the page but that didn't help.

It works here outside of Joomla [working slidetoggle](http://wwagora.com/maketem/templates/brandme/test.html) but not when I put it in the template's index.php file [non-working slidetoggle](http://wwagora.com/maketem/)

In the Joomla template index.php, I have loaded jquery (version 1.10.2 comes with Joomla 3) and jqueryui

```
// Add JavaScript Frameworks
JHtml::_('bootstrap.framework');
JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
JHtml::_('jquery.ui');
```

I've inserted:

```
<div class="toggalcontainer">
    <div id="showHideDiv">Welcome To FaceBook.</div>
    <i id="divtoggle" class="slideit"></i>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">   
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $( "#divtoggle" ).click(function() {
      $( "#showHideDiv" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
        // Animation complete.
        $("#divtoggle" ).toggleClass('down')

      });
    });
});
</script>
```

in *index.php* where the div should display.

The css is

```
#showHideDiv{
    color: #fff;
    background-color:#47639E;
    padding:10px;

}
.toggalcontainer{
    width:100%
} 
.slideit {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 8px;
    background-image: url("../light.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.up{

}
.down{
  background-position: -63px 0 ;
}
```

It's displaying, I just can't figure out why it won't toggle.  I replaced all '$' with 'jquery' because Joomla docs [use jQuery instead of $ doc](http://docs.joomla.org/Javascript_Frameworks) says to use jquery namespace instead of $, but that did nothing so I changed it back to $.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to use the *all* of the following:

```
JHtml::_('bootstrap.framework');
JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
JHtml::_('jquery.ui');
```

All 3 of these lines import jQuery in *noConflict* mode.

You can remove `JHtml::_('jquery.framework');`.

As you're using noConflict mode, you need to replace your jQuery with the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){    
    $("#divtoggle").on('click', function() {
        $("#showHideDiv").slideToggle("slow", function() {
            $('#divtoggle').toggleClass('down');
        });
    });
});
```

As you can see, I have used `jQuery` in the global scope, and passed `$` through as an alias. I've also tweaked the click function.

Hope this helps